# How can we get updated location after app is terminated?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

We have used

`significantLocationChange`(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant_change_location_service)

for update location but it gives location update sometimes and so it
 is not consistenly giving the location update.

What is the best way to get updated  location frequently when app is
 in terminated stage (not in foreground / not in background)

Comment: This is an old question, I suggest you to research about background tasks app killed. You will find a way. I've implemented a solution for this but can't publish my code due to compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Background modes for Location updates for your app. You can do this by selecting your Project -> Capabilities -> Background Modes and enable Location updates.

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to do that, IMHO. If the app is terminated you will get no frequent updates, it was the users choice to terminate your app and Apple respects this. iOS does not collect location data in the background and handles it over to your app when your app is started again.

Comment: Terrible wrong. You have many different ways to wake up (relaunch) and work with locations in background. There are plenty of apps published to track users. You can use background task, combine `significanLocationChanges` with `startUpdatingLocation`, and use all of them together

Comment: As I said, you can combine different approaches and get your location updates as you want

Comment: But only after a significant change, or immediately after the app was terminated?

Comment: You can even avoid app being killed using background tasks. It's up to you to kill users battery or make something smarter. But for your question, can be by significant location, can be by notifications, by silent notifications, by beacons... etc

Comment: If your app gets terminated you will need to wait for something then, like you said, significant location or beacon or silent notification what ever. So you will not receive location changes immediately after the app is terminated. Maybe trough tricks, like silent notification... am I right? If you have a trick, then please provide it here so we all can learn, and thx for the down vote btw.

Comment: The votes (not just mine btw) is related to your answer, which is wrong and lacking technical background

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is technically wrong? There is no way to get immediate location changes after your app was terminated, and iOS does not collect all the updates you missed, so please explain what is wrong, I'm eager to learn. There might be tricks though, as you mentioned, so please tell how to do it, no code needed to be published. People are very fast in judging here, you experienced it as well.